# How do I create/publish a report in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I installed SQL Server 2014 with Reporting Services but I don't how understand how to create and publish a report so that users can run it on the report server on IIS.

These are the programs that have been installed when I search 'SQL':

- SQL Server 2014 Management Studio
- SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services
  Configuration Manager

Are these the only required programs to be able to create and publish reports? Which do I use to create a report?

Comment: Too localized, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing a report has not changed much in SQL Server since 2005. Developing a report changed when SQL Server 2012 came out just with the tool that you would use. I would suggest you start out by going through the [Stairway To SQL Server Reporting Services by Jessica M. Moss](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72382/). After reading through that series I would suggest getting a book on SSRS, anything by Stacia Misner on the subject is a good start.

Comment: I downloaded SQL Server 2014 with Reporting Services, but within those 2 programs I have listed above I do not see the option to create a new report, design a new report, publish a new report etc. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jack A book that explains this all in more detail. You will not be able to get that level of information and help through a QA site.